# How to read values from the last column from a file with different number of columns?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a text file with data.
In each line there is one or two words and one number, so the problem is, that sometimes there are 2 columns and sometimes 3.

```
aaa bbb 4
ccc 10
ddd eee 3
fff 5
```

I only need those numbers. How to copy them to a list in Python?

I tried with

```
file = open("data.txt","r")
data = file.readlines()
result = []
for line in data:
    result.append(line.split(' ')[-1])
file.close()
```

But I don't know how to get rid of '\n' in the end of number? Because when I change `result.append(line.split(' ')[-1])`
to

`result.append(int(line.split(' ')[-1]))`, it doesn't work.
Is there a better way?

Comment: Read the file line-by-line, in each line extract the number by using a regex matching group, convert it to `int` and you're done.

Comment: is the line number the number is in relevant?

Comment: to remove the `'\n'` characters, use [str.strip()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip): use `result.append(line.strip().split(' ')[-1])`. ***But*** if you want them as *numbers* add a cast to **int**: `result.append(int(line.strip().split(' ')[-1]))` then you'll have `[4, 10, 3, 5]` as probably expected.

Answer (score 0):

If the line number is irrelevant:

```
import re

s = '''aaa bbb 4
ccc 10
ddd eee 3
fff 5'''

matches = re.findall('\d+', s)
for match in matches:
    print(match)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you split each line by the space you would have a list of everything in the line. You can then use `lst[-1]` to get the last element in that list. for example:

```
for line in file:
    lst=line.split(" ")
    lastCol=lst[-1]
```

this should get you just the last column in each line. If you also need to store it as a number you can do `lastCol=int(lst[-1])` as the last line.

EDIT:

You can use `strip()` to remove the `"\n"` and all other white-space at the end of the line:

```
lst=line.strip().split(" ")
```

Answer (score 0):

When python reads text files, it also reads in the newline characters (`'\n'` at the end of each line). You may want to remove these characters, and since these are numbers cast the value to `int` before appending to your list:

```
file = open("data.txt","r")
data = file.readlines()
result = []
for line in data:
    result.append(int(line.strip().split(' ')[-1])) # the only line changed 
file.close()

print(result)
```

output:

```
[4, 10, 3, 5]
```

Answer (score -1):

```
file = open("data.txt","r")
data = file.readlines()
result = []
for line in data:
    result.append(float(line.split(' ')[-1].replace('\n', '')))
file.close()
```